# How to create list of dictionary from nested list of strings in python?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have dataframe with sparse columns values and I vectorized it, now I want to create key-value dictionary by row-wise. However, I need to create dictionary where column name is key and column value is value by each row of dataframe. How to create such dictionary from my current attempt? any thoughts?

**approach 1**

here is minimal reproducible data that I used:

```
df_dict={'order': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 9, 9: 10}, 'code0': {0: nan, 1: " '40'", 2: " '98'", 3: " '98'", 4: " '52'", 5: " '52'", 6: " '52'", 7: " '52'", 8: " '40'", 9: " '58'"}, 'code1': {0: "  ('VA','HC','NIH','SAP','AUS','HOL','ATT','COL','UCL')", 1: nan, 2: " ('ATT','NC')", 3: " ('ATT','VA','NC')", 4: " 'NC'", 5: " 'NC'", 6: " 'NC'", 7: " 'NC'", 8: " 'VA'", 9: " 'CE'"}, 'code2': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: " ('103','104','105','106','31')", 3: " ('104','105','106','31')", 4: " '109'", 5: " '109'", 6: " '109'", 7: " '109'", 8: " '11'", 9: " ('109')"}, 'code3': {0: nan, 1: " '518'", 2: " '810'", 3: nan, 4: " ('610','620','682','642','621','611')", 5: " ('396','340','394','393','240')", 6: " ('612','790','110')", 7: " ('730','320','350','379','812','374')", 8: " ('113','174','131','115')", 9: " ('423','114')"}, 'code4': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: " 'computer science'", 3: "  'computer science'", 4: " 'biology'", 5: " 'biology'", 6: "biology'", 7: "biology'", 8: nan, 9: nan}, 'code5': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: " ('12','18')", 6: " ('12','16','18','19')", 7: " ('12','18','19')", 8: " ('11','19','31')", 9: " '31'"}, 'code6': {0: nan, 1: " '594'", 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: " ('712','479','297','639','452','172')", 5: nan, 6: " ('285','295','236','239','269','284','237')", 7: nan, 8: " ('164','157','388','158')", 9: " ('372','238')"}, 'rules_desc': {0: 'rules1', 1: 'rules2', 2: 'rules2', 3: 'rules2', 4: 'rules2', 5: 'rules2', 6: 'rules2', 7: 'rules2', 8: 'rules2', 9: 'rules2'}}

import pandas as pd
df1=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_dict())

cols = df1.columns.values
res=[",".join("{}:{}".format(*t) for t in zip(cols, row)) for _, row in df1[cols].iterrows()]
```

for now I am getting list but needs to have key such as column name as key and column value bounded to it. How can I do this in python?

Instead, I tried like this also:

```
res=[df1.iloc[i].astype(str).tolist() for i in range(0, len(df1))]
```

I am getting error when I tried `res.to_dict()`:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_dict'

this is fine, but I need column name assign to it and create dictionary. how can I do this in python? any idea?

**approach 2: new update - much better but still incorrect**

```
cols = df1.columns.values
for i in range(0, len(df1)):
    ss=df1.iloc[i][cols].dropna().astype(str).tolist()  # this is good
    my_dict = {k: cols for k in ss}  # doing this incorrect
    print(my_dict )
```

but here able to drop the column with `nan` but don't know how to get correct key which is column name. I think I need somewhere between approach 1 and approach 2, don't know how to get my desired output. any idea?

**desired output**

I want to create key-value list for each rows of dataframe, like dictionary. here is my part of my expected output after clean up nan values:

```
{{'order':1, 'code': ('VA','HC','NIH','SAP','AUS','HOL','ATT','COL','UCL'), 'rules_desc': rules1},
{'order':2, 'code0': 40, 'code3':518, 'code6':594, 'rules_desc': rules2},
{'order':3, 'code0':98, 'code1':('ATT','NC'), 'code2':('103','104','105','106','31'), 'code3':810, 'code4': computer_science, 'rules_desc': rules2},
...
}
```

Comment: What's the key and what's the value? Then just https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html.

Comment: @ifly6 I think you didn't get my point, key is column name, value is columns value by row-wise; now I make list of list from dataframe, but need to create correct format of dictionary as desired output. any ideas how to do this?

Comment: You have two questions here: (1.) How could I call `.dropna()` (or map `NaN` to some sentinel value, that part's not yet clear), and (2.) how can I turn such a filtered DataFrame into a collection of dicts? You haven't clarified why `.to_dict()` doesn't work for that second part.

Comment: @J_H updated my post with minimal example if gist is not right way to see the dataand focus on one single question, answered why `.to_dict()` doesn't work. do you mind to share your thoughts if possible? I got stuck here what is right way to do. thanks

Comment: @J_H thanks for the input but that's not what I want, I did better attempt than posted answer, maybe I can clarify my post more. I am not able to delete my post and repost with better clarity but you posted answer here.

Answer (score 1):

There exists a technical problem
that you hope one or more people will solve, possibly
including yourself.
Here is my current understanding
of the problem as presented.

The "expected" values apparently
don't match your expectation.
It would be helpful if you could
describe them in code.

Maybe you wish to `json.loads`
some of those columns?

```
import json
import unittest

import pandas as pd
from pandas import NA as nan


class NestTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @staticmethod
    def _get_dictionary():
        return {
            "order": {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 9, 9: 10},
            "code0": {
                0: nan,
                1: " '40'",
                2: " '98'",
                3: " '98'",
                4: " '52'",
                5: " '52'",
                6: " '52'",
                7: " '52'",
                8: " '40'",
                9: " '58'",
            },
            "code1": {
                0: "  ('VA','HC','NIH','SAP','AUS','HOL','ATT','COL','UCL')",
                1: nan,
                2: " ('ATT','NC')",
                3: " ('ATT','VA','NC')",
                4: " 'NC'",
                5: " 'NC'",
                6: " 'NC'",
                7: " 'NC'",
                8: " 'VA'",
                9: " 'CE'",
            },
            "code2": {
                0: nan,
                1: nan,
                2: " ('103','104','105','106','31')",
                3: " ('104','105','106','31')",
                4: " '109'",
                5: " '109'",
                6: " '109'",
                7: " '109'",
                8: " '11'",
                9: " ('109')",
            },
            "code3": {
                0: nan,
                1: " '518'",
                2: " '810'",
                3: nan,
                4: " ('610','620','682','642','621','611')",
                5: " ('396','340','394','393','240')",
                6: " ('612','790','110')",
                7: " ('730','320','350','379','812','374')",
                8: " ('113','174','131','115')",
                9: " ('423','114')",
            },
            "code4": {
                0: nan,
                1: nan,
                2: " 'computer science'",
                3: "  'computer science'",
                4: " 'biology'",
                5: " 'biology'",
                6: "biology'",
                7: "biology'",
                8: nan,
                9: nan,
            },
            "code5": {
                0: nan,
                1: nan,
                2: nan,
                3: nan,
                4: nan,
                5: " ('12','18')",
                6: " ('12','16','18','19')",
                7: " ('12','18','19')",
                8: " ('11','19','31')",
                9: " '31'",
            },
            "code6": {
                0: nan,
                1: " '594'",
                2: nan,
                3: nan,
                4: " ('712','479','297','639','452','172')",
                5: nan,
                6: " ('285','295','236','239','269','284','237')",
                7: nan,
                8: " ('164','157','388','158')",
                9: " ('372','238')",
            },
            "rules_desc": {
                0: "rules1",
                1: "rules2",
                2: "rules2",
                3: "rules2",
                4: "rules2",
                5: "rules2",
                6: "rules2",
                7: "rules2",
                8: "rules2",
                9: "rules2",
            },
        }

    def test_how_to_create_list_of_dictionary_from_nested_list_of_strings(self):
        df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(self._get_dictionary())
        df1 = df1[:3]  # Let's focus on just a subset, the first 3 rows

        self.assertEqual(
            [
                {
                    "code0": None,
                    "code1": "  ('VA','HC','NIH','SAP','AUS','HOL','ATT','COL','UCL')",
                    "code2": None,
                    "code3": None,
                    "code4": None,
                    "code5": None,
                    "code6": None,
                    "order": 1,
                    "rules_desc": "rules1",
                },
                {
                    "code0": " '40'",
                    "code1": None,
                    "code2": None,
                    "code3": " '518'",
                    "code4": None,
                    "code5": None,
                    "code6": " '594'",
                    "order": 2,
                    "rules_desc": "rules2",
                },
                {
                    "code0": " '98'",
                    "code1": " ('ATT','NC')",
                    "code2": " ('103','104','105','106','31')",
                    "code3": " '810'",
                    "code4": " 'computer science'",
                    "code5": None,
                    "code6": None,
                    "order": 3,
                    "rules_desc": "rules2",
                },
            ],
            json.loads(df1.to_json(orient="records")),
        )
```